# unigrams & bigrams (tf-idf) less accurate than just unigrams (ff-idf)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, regression, tf-idf

This is a question about linear regression with ngrams, using Tf-IDF (term frequency - inverse document frequency). To do this, I am using numpy sparse matrices and sklearn for linear regression.

I have 53 cases and over 6000 features when using unigrams. The predictions are based on cross validation using LeaveOneOut.

When I create a tf-idf sparse matrix of only unigram scores, I get slightly better predictions than when I create a tf-idf sparse matrix of unigram+bigram scores. The more columns I add to the matrix (columns for trigram, quadgram, quintgrams, etc.), the less accurate the regression prediction.

Is this common? How is this possible? I would have thought that the more features, the better.

Comment: What is your task (e.g., document classification) and what kind of/how much data do you have?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not common for bigrams to perform worse than unigrams, but there are situations where it may happen. In particular, adding extra features may lead to overfitting. Tf-idf is unlikely to alleviate this, as longer n-grams will be rarer, leading to higher idf values.

I'm not sure what kind of variable you're trying to predict, and I've never done regression on text, but here's some comparable results from literature to get you thinking:

- In random text generation with small (but non-trivial) training sets, 7-grams tend to reconstruct the input text almost verbatim, i.e. cause complete overfit, while trigrams are more likely to generate "new" but still somewhat grammatical/recognizable text (see [Jurafsky & Martin](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~martin/slp.html); can't remember which chapter and I don't have my copy handy).
- In classification-style NLP tasks performed with kernel machines, quadratic kernels tend to fare better than cubic ones because the latter often overfit on the training set. Note that unigram+bigram features can be thought of as a subset of the quadratic kernel's feature space, and {1,2,3}-grams of that of the cubic kernel.

Exactly what is happening depends on your training set; it might simply be too small.

Comment: My results are obtained by Leave One Out cross validation. I have 53 samples and each sample is taken out of the training set before it is trained. Doesnt this in itself prevent over fitting?

Comment: @Zach: no; cross validation is just a minimum requirement to do any kind of evaluation when there's no separate validation or test set. 53 samples is a *very* small training set. Also, I just saw your messages on the scikit-learn mailing list and I read that you're doing sentiment analysis. In that case, drop tf-idf and use raw frequencies, sublinear tf or boolean term occurrences. idf underestimates the importance of sentiment words, because it's designed to find topical similarity which is indicated by the rarer words in text.

Comment: 53 samples is very few for text classification. Rather than trying to tweak the feature extraction and learning algorithm you should better invest time in labeling more data (semi-automatically, maybe using external sources of data).

Comment: @Zach annotate at least 100 * n_classes (e.g. 200 for binary classification). Then compute cross validation score on 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90% and 100% of your data and consider the test error curve: you should observe some diminishing returns by considering the slope of each segment. The tradeoff between accuracy improvement and annotation cost is problem specific but this curve should give you the tool to make an informed decision (i.e. not completely in the dark :).

Comment: @ogrisel in my case it would cost me $6000 to annotate 100*n_classes, so not feasable for me! Out of curiosity, where did you get that figure from?

Comment: How many classes do you have in your case?

If you want to have a classifier to be able to generalize you need to show it a corpus of documents that cover all the words of a vocabulary of topics statistically linked to a class. You cannot expect 10 documents per class to cover extensively all the interesting vocabulary of topics related to those classes.

If you don't have enough labeled data and labeling is too costly, then pure supervised machine learning is probably not the solution to your problem.

Comment: On the other hand, machine learning (unsupervised learning, semi-supervised learning and active learning) could help lower the cost of labeling new samples. However I don't have ready to use scikit-learn active learning loop.

Answer (score 9):

As larsmans said, adding more variables / features makes it easier for the model to overfit hence lose in test accuracy. In the master branch of scikit-learn there is now a `min_df` parameter to cut-off any feature with less than that number of occurrences. Hence `min_df==2` to `min_df==5` might help you get rid of spurious bi-grams.

Alternatively you can use L1 or L1 + L2 penalized linear regression (or classification) using either the following classes:

- sklearn.linear_model.Lasso (regression)
- sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet (regression)
- sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor (regression) with penalty == 'elastic_net' or 'l1'
- sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier (classification) with penalty == 'elastic_net' or 'l1'

This will make it possible to ignore spurious features and lead to a sparse model with many zero weights for noisy features. Grid Searching the regularization parameters will be very important though.

You can also try univariate feature selection such as done the [text classification example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html#example-document-classification-20newsgroups-py) of scikit-learn (check the `SelectKBest` and `chi2` utilities.

Comment: `chi2` feature selection won't actually work for regression, though. It might be hacked to work with binned regression outcomes.

Comment: When you say min_df is in the Master Branch, do you mean the development version beyond 0.11?

Comment: Yes the master branch of the official github repo: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn

Comment: Note: the `min_df` is now part of the released versions of scikit-learn (0.14 and later).